# How to Initialize State for each Element in Array ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, state, initializing

New to React and building a geography app. I have an array of continents
`uniqueRegions = ['Asia', 'America', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Oceania', 'Polar']` in my props as `this.props.uniqueRegions`. In my component, I want to set the state of a property `visible` on each of those continents. I could hard-code it, but I don't want to do that. How can I possibly make that happen?

I tried using the spread operator as such

```
state = {
  [ ...this.props.uniqueRegions]: {visible: 5}
    };
```

but that obviously is incorrect syntax.

Also, I've tried initializing the visible property in setState, but it always returns undefined.

```
loadMore = (region) => {
        console.log(this.state[region])
        if(this.state[region])
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            [region]: {visible: 5}
        }))
    }
```

Below is how my region data is passed and currently set to State.

```
filterRegion = (region) =>{
        if(region !==undefined ){
            this.setState({
                [region]: {countries: ['']}
            })
          return Axios
           .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/' + region)
           .then(res => {
             if(res.status === 200 && res !== null){
              this.setState(prevState =>({
                [region]: {...prevState[region],
                    countries: (res && res.data || [])} 
              }))
              } else {
               throw new Error('No country found');
             }
             })
             .catch(error => {
               console.log(error)
               return []
             });
         };
        };

    loadMore = (region) => {
        console.log(this.state[region])
        if(this.state[region])
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            [region]: {visible: 5}
        }))
    }

    render(){
        const handleRegion =(region) =>{
            this.filterRegion(region);
            if(this.state[region] && this.state[region].open){
                this.setState(prevState =>({
                    [region]: {...prevState[region],
                        open: false
                    }
                  }))
            } else {
                this.setState(prevState =>({
                    [region]: {...prevState[region],
                        open: true
                    }
                  }))
            }
        }
```

I've been able to set properties on a particular region, i.e. [region].open, but cannot seem to make it work with visible.

**EDIT/PROBLEM SOLVED**

After some back and forth with Junius, I adjusted my code. What fixed it for me was setting a variable that contained all of the properties per array element that I wanted, adding them to the array, and then setting the entire array as state using the spread operator.

```
        if (!regions) {
            console.log('no regions')
          return;
        }
        if(regions) 
        console.log(regions);
        const regionsState = {};

        regions.forEach((region, index) => {
            if(this.state[region] && this.state[region].countries[0]){
                regionsState[region] = { visible: 5, countries: this.state[region].countries, open: false};
            } else {
                this.filterRegion(region);
                regionsState[region] = { visible: 5, countries: [], open: false};
            }
        });

        // set state here outside the foreach function
         this.setState((prevState => ({
           ...regionsState
         })))
      };
```

Lastly, I couldn't get the data to initialize properly. At first, I was loading the data on a click, but that's neither ideal nor realistic; running the code in **componentDidMount** wouldn't fire after the props were loaded. The solution for me was running the function in ***componentDidUpdate***. My state now initializes correctly. Thanks again Junius for the help!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the desired state should look like?

Comment: Yes, the desired state should look like `state: {Asia: {visible: 5}, countries: [Array] `. The visible property helps to determine how many countries are shown at a time. A load more button will change the visible state and show that many more countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new object and add each region  to the object as a property.

```
setDynamicRegions = regions => {
  if (!regions) {
    return;
  }

  const regionsState = {};

  regions.forEach((item, index) => {
    regionsState[item] = { visible: 0 };
  });

  //   this.setState({
  //     regionsState: regionsState
 //   });
};
```

```js
const uniqueRegions = [
    "Asia",
    "America",
    "Europe",
    "Africa",
    "Oceania",
    "Polar"
    ];

    const setDynamicRegions = regions => {
    if (!regions) {
        return;
    }

    const regionsState = {};

    regions.forEach((item, index) => {
        regionsState[item] = { visible: 0 };
    });

    //   this.setState({
    //     regionsState: regionsState
    //   });
    console.log(regionsState);
    };

    setDynamicRegions(uniqueRegions);
```

Comment: This works well for setting the values to regionState, but when attempting to set state, the app crashes with this error : `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: how do you set state?

Comment: I'm currently setting state in the place where this.setState is grayed out.

Comment: ````regions.forEach((item, index) => {
                regionsState[item] = { visible: 0 };
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    [item]: {...prevState[item], visible: 0, countries: []}
                }));
                console.log(this.state[item])
            });
            };````

Comment: No you are setting state inside `.forEach()` it won't work, it'll throw that error, move set state below foreach.

Comment: No, I set and ran the function inside the render function, and it returned the same error: maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: it shouldn't be in a render function. let me see your code paste it here https://codeshare.io/2jJOnM

Comment: https://github.com/capstonednc/geography-app My laptop is dying, and I'm currently unable to charge it. Perhaps you can fork the app, or I can try stackblitz again when I'm back online. I truly appreciate your assistance thus far!

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple empty object in state:

```
state = {
    visibleRegions: {}
}
```

Making region visible is as simple as define property with region as key

```
visibleRegions[region] = true;
```

Condition `!visibleRegions[region]` will cover `undefined` and `false` ... `!!visibleRegions[region]` for visible state.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a checkbox, you can adapt it as you wish to any element, it is the same principle, I don't know if this is what you look for because I am not sure if I got your question, but I hope at least it gives you an idea. Take your array from your props `const {myData} = this.props` Good luck :)

`

class Geo extends Component {
    state = {
        visible: false,
        uniqueRegions: ['Asia', 'America', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Oceania', 'Polar']
    };

```
handleChecked = () => {
    this.setState({
        visible: !this.state.visible
    });
};
render() {
    const { uniqueRegions } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChecked} value={uniqueRegions} />

            {uniqueRegions.map(region => {
                if (this.state.visible) {
                    return (
                        <p>
                            these are my regions {region}
                        </p>
                    );
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default Geo;
 `